# How do i embed a caption in UIimage to be exported to email

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My question is simple, i am trying to send an image in an email but add a caption.

**Here is what i am using for the image -**

```
NSData *imageDatatwo = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image);
[mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatatwo mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagetwo"];


- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSData *imageDatatwo = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatatwo mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagetwo"];

       [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    } }
- (void)mailComposeControllerthree:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put text in the email body along with the image or composite text onto the image before you attach it?

Answer (score 2):

The image and the captions need to be part of a view. (1 subview for the image, another subview for the text .  - Once you have that it is a simple matter to convert the CALAyer of the view into a png or jpg file. Then just put the code to attach the png file to email - (note the view may or may not be displayed on the device but it needs to be refreshed (setneedsdisplay)  code follows:

```
  [vc.view setNeedsDisplay];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vc.view.bounds.size, vc.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [vc.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Sharing"];

    NSString *pngName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_QRU_Free.png",file_name.text];
    NSString *pngfile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:pngName];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:pngfile atomically:YES];
```